# controlling dynamic content with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to control buttons with dynamic ids 
$num represents the number of buttons 
but this code wont work because on click the variable $i will take the same value when exiting the loop :
how can I fix this ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $num=("#num").attr("value");
    for ($i=0;$i<=$num;$i++){
    $("#createNew"+$i).click(function(){
        $("#j"+$i).hide();
        $("#cNew"+$i).slideToggle(1000);
    });
    $("#join"+i).click(function(){
        $("#cNew"+$i).hide();
        $("#j"+$i).slideToggle(1000);
    });
    }
});
```

the php code:

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
      echo "<div class=\"well project\">";
      echo"<h1 id=\"course\">".$row['courseID']." </h1></br>";
      echo "<p>".$row['description']."</p></br></br>";
      echo "<input type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default bt\" id=\"createNew\"value=\"create new\" >";
      echo "<input type=\"button \" class=\"btn btn-default bt\" id=\"join\" value=\"join\">";
      echo "<div id=\"cNew".$i."\" style=\"display:none\"></br><form method=\"POST\" action=\"createNewProject.php?reg=".$row['regID']."\" ><label for=\"title\" >Project title</label><input type=\"textbox\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"title\"></br><label for =\" Pdescription\">description</label><textarea name=\"Pdescription\" class=\"form-control\"></textarea></br> <input type=\"submit\" vlaue=\"create\" class=\"btn btn-default bt\" ></form></div>";

      echo"</br></br><div id=\"j".$i."\" style=\"display:none\"><form method=\"post\"  action=\"joinProject.php?reg=".$row['regID']."\"><label for=\"pId\">Enter the project ID</label><input type=\"textbox\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"pId\"></br> <input type=\"submit\"  value=\"Send requst\" class=\"btn btn-default bt\"></br></form></div>";
      echo "</div>";
      $i++;
  }
  }
  else 
      echo"<div class=\"well project\"><h1>No new projects</h1></div>";
      echo "<input type=\"textbox\" id=\"num\" value=\"".$i."\" style=\"display:none\">";
```

Comment: Show us your html, it looks to me as though there is a much better way to do this with jQuery.

Comment: $num=parseInt(("#num").attr("value"));

Comment: @user10099 javascript is loosely typed so parseint is actually unnecessary here.

Comment: it is working without parseInt the problem is inside .click function

Comment: @jcuenod I have added the php code

Comment: On line 2 after $(document).ready(), you're missing the "$" before ("#num") (should be $("#num") ). In the click callback for #join, you're referring to "i" when the correct variable would be "$i". You should also use the "var" keyword for JavaScript or else your variables will be global.

Comment: the problem is on click function for example if num is 2 onclick  on createNew0  the value of i inside the function will be 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be best just to use event delegation for this. We can use a dynamic number as part of the selector as well.

```
$('body').on('click', '[id^="createNew"], [id^="join"]', function(){
    var id = $(this).prop('id').split('createNew')[1];
    $('#j'+id).hide();
    $('#cNew'+id).slideToggle(1000);
});

$('body').on('click', '[id^="join"]', function(){
    var id = $(this).prop('id').split('join')[1];
    $('#cNew'+id).hide();
    $('#j'+id).slideToggle(1000);
});
```

The implementation would function [something like this:](http://jsfiddle.net/ebmn8Lck/)